# Can't access GCP Access Secret Manager from Dataproc sparkjob

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-secret-manager

I am trying to fetch GCP secret manager secret from dataproc spark job. But I am getting the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/secretmanager/v1/AccessSecretVersionResponse".
I have added the jars "google-cloud-secretmanager-1.4.2.jar" and "gax-1.62.0.jar" in the dataproc spark job dependency.

I am using the code mentioned in the below GCP link.
https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is the image-version of your cluster? Can you share the commands you are using to create the cluster and to submit the job?

Comment: image-version is "2.0-debian10" and I am submitting the spark job through UI option "SUBMIT JOB" by providing all the required information i.e. main class ,jars path.

Answer (score 1):

2.0-debian10 has python >= 3.0 installed. google-cloud-secretmanager-1.4.2.jar does not support python >= 3.0 (https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-secret-manager/1.0.0/). Please use a later version of google-cloud-secretmanager.

Comment: I not using python, I am using scala 2.12.12. and google-cloud-secretmanager-1.4.2.jar is the latest jar. Below is the maven link of this jar for reference. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-secretmanager.

Comment: Got it. Can you share the exact command you are using to submit the spark job? Just want to make sure that jars are added correctly.

Comment: I am using Dataproc workflow template to submit the sparkjob with on demand cluster.
What I noticed is that, after adding the jar, I am getting the error for sub dependencies too. I added up to the 10 jars and still, I am getting the error for another class.

Can you please suggest, what is the best approach to access the secret manager from Dataproc?

Comment: The problem with secretmanager in combination with scala spark is mostly google guava. As Spark uses a really old version of guava (in my case 11.0) and secretmanger uses 31. There is only the way to shade (relocate) the secretmanagers guava classes.

Comment: @SandroHörler Thanks for your response and help.